# Add to registry key from file c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, addition, registry

i'm use this code for add file .reg to registry, but this method doesn't work. Windows said to have import the file but don't appear the registry keys.

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s key.reg");
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Does it have to originate from a file? Is there any reason why [Native Registry Modification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) isn't an option?

Comment: Can you show the content of your `key.reg` file?

Comment: file reg: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"MyFirstApp"=dword:00001f40

Comment: Also when you say it doesn't appear in the registry, make sure you're looking at the right version of the registry. A 64 bit system can have different registry keys for 64 and 32 bit versions of software http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: yes man the registry appear to Wow6432Node\microsft... but I don't want them to appear under wow6432node

Comment: There may be permission issues, or other reasons why it won't allow to import. I would suggest removing the /s option so you could see the prompts and error messages (if any) and try then. It may tell you that it can't import for whatever reason. Once it works properly, you can add the /s switch back in.

Answer (score 2):

As brad suggested, is there a reason why you can't use the [Registry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx)? If the file is still having problems, you could always parse it some data structure and use the registry class to insert it into the registry.